# How to use NavigationService in a ChildWindow in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I have a button on the Childwindow, which should navigate to a Phoneapplication page.

I am using the NavigationService.Navigate(), but it says "NavigationService cannot be used in the current context ".

How to use the NavigationService in a Child Window ??

Answer (score 1):

If it "can't be used in the current context" you may be better off looking at a different way to trigger the navigation rather than trying to do something the system says it can't do.

I'd recommend using a messaging system to send a message to the page hosting the child window and then have that trigger the navigation.

Also note that you should be making navigation requests from the UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But i want to the naviagtion on the button click to a page other than the parent page from which it is called. Is it possible to do something like that with ChildWindows ??..If not is there an other control or option for this ??

Comment: @Sri yes, have the button click on the ChildWindow send a message which is listened to by the host page and on receipt of that message trigger the navigation.

Comment: (Application.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Navigate(uri);...This code is what i wanted...It works fine now.